# Confused about random_state in sklearn

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

So, basically, I'm using a RF for descriptive modelling as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y), y)
class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
class_weights
```

> {0: 0.5561096747856852, 1: 4.955559597429368}

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight=class_weights, random_state=0)

cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring='f1').mean()
```

And plotting variables importance as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_importances(clf, features, n):
    importances = clf.feature_importances_
    indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

    if n:
        indices = indices[:n]

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.title("Feature importances")
    plt.bar(range(len(indices)), importances[indices], align='center')
    plt.xticks(range(len(indices)), features[indices], rotation=90)
    plt.xlim([-1, len(indices)])
    plt.show()

    return features[indices]

imp = plot_importances(clf, X.columns, 30)
```

I was expecting **variable importances** to be **the same across multiple runs**. However, their importances changes whenever I re-run the notebook.

I don't understand why is that. Is it related to the `cross_val_score` method somehow?

Comment: `cross_val_score` will split the data using a StratifiedKFold which is also dependent on `random_state`, so it will affect the data reaching the RandomForest and hence the score changes.

Comment: The default for StatifiedKFold is `shuffle=False`, and `random_state` is only used when `shuffle=True`, so not sure whether this is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem. For me the variable importances does remain the same for multiple runs when I produce some data using:

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                       n_features=10,
                       n_informative=3,
                       n_redundant=0,
                       n_repeated=0,
                       n_classes=2,
                       random_state=0,
                       shuffle=False)
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
```

Also changing the data to have an uneven weighting by selecting the first 750 y/X data points does not lead to differences in importances.

What data do you use?

Comment: Unfortunately the data is confidential (client). I have never faced before, that's why I posted a question here.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you reproduce your problem using the data I generated above? What version of sklearn do you use?